# Punto dentro de polígono, algoritmo de Ray Casting

Tags: google-maps, genexus

Buenas tardes, estoy con el siguiente problema. Implementé en Genexus usando Map Control el algoritmo para saber si un 
[Punto dentro de un polìgono](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?28751,Como%20determinar%20si%20un%20punto%20esta%20en%20un%20pol%C3%ADgono,). Como estaba en c# lo traduje a genexus, este es el resultado:

```
parm(in:&GxMapPoint,in:&GxMapPolygon,out:&salida);

&salida='N'
&PuntoXY=&GxMapPoint.PointLat.Trim()+", "+&GxMapPoint.PointLong.Trim()
&y = &GeoLocationAPI1.GetLatitude(&PuntoXY)
&x= &GeoLocationAPI1.GetLongitude(&PuntoXY)
&j=&GxMapPolygon.Paths.Count
for &i= 1 to (&GxMapPolygon.Paths.Count)
    &PuntoI=&GxMapPolygon.Paths.Item(&i).PathLat.Trim()+", "+&GxMapPolygon.Paths.Item(&i).PathLong
    &PuntoJ=&GxMapPolygon.Paths.Item(&j).PathLat.Trim()+", "+&GxMapPolygon.Paths.Item(&j).PathLong
    &PointLatI=&GeoLocationAPI1.GetLatitude(&PuntoI)    
    &PointLongI=&GeoLocationAPI1.GetLongitude(&PuntoI)
    &PointLatJ=&GeoLocationAPI1.GetLatitude(&PuntoJ)
    &PointLongJ=&GeoLocationAPI1.GetLongitude(&PuntoJ)
    if (&PointLongI >= &x)<>(&PointLongJ>=&x)
        &valor= (&PointLatJ - &y) * (&x - &PointLongI) / ( &PointLongJ - &PointLongI) + &PointLatI      
        if (&y < &valor)    
            &salida='S'
            exit
        endif
    endif
    &j=&i
endfor
```

Pero tengo un problema, me está asumiendo algunos puntos que no están dentro del polígono,y me está haciendo dudar si no le pifié a algo en el algoritmo que no me estoy dando cuenta. Les muestro un ejemplo de lo que detecté con un par de imágenes.

Acá funciona correctamente determina que 2 puntos están en la zona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá funciona mal los puntos marcados estan fuera de la zona y los toma como que están dentro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La pregunta es, ¿Esta correcto el algoritmo que implemente? Parece como si mirando el vértice del triángulo que está mas a la izquierda, si quedan puntos por debajo a la derecha, los incluye como dentro de la zona. Y eso está mal.

Otro dato, las variables que usé son Numeric signed de 16 con 12 posiciones decimales.

Agradezco desde ya alguna ayuda, observación, corrección, etc.

Gracias, saludos
Bruno

Comment: Aquí tienes un ejemplo de implementación del algoritmo en Python: https://github.com/joseahr/pyGeo/blob/master/Topologia/PointInPolygon.py

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, comentarte que en la versión 15 de genexus ya tienes integrada esta funcionalidad a partir del tipo de datos geográfico. (la cual utiliza las funcionalidades de la base de datos para resolverla).

Esto significa que si almacenas los valores en un atributo de tipo Geography, tienes una función `Intersect` que retorna un booleano, si el punto (u otro tipo geography) está incluido en el  polígono. El código queda muy sencillo, sería algo así:

```
for each 
   where AttGeography.Intersect(&GeoPoint) 
   ...
endfor
```

Acá está el detalle en la documentación : [Geography data type](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?32408,Geography%20data%20type)

En el caso que no sea viable pasar a la última versión y usar el tipo de datos, hay que revisar con mas detalle la implementación de Ray casting que hiciste.

Basándome en la implementación que esta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716268/point-in-polygon-algorithm), parecería que no esta iterando de la misma forma. Una forma rápida de probarlo es copiar ese código y embeberlo en un procedimiento, algo del tipo:

```
&lat = -34.908168
&long =  -56.152393
&vector(1) = "-34.902473,-56.164040"
&vector(2) = "-34.903248,-56.158421"
...
&nvert = len(&vector)
&c = False
csharp for([!&i!] = 0, [!&j!] = [!&nvert!] - 1; [!&i!] = &long )  (&longitude1 >= &long)) and
        (&lat
```

Si eso sí te funciona, vemos de resolverlo sin embeber la líneas, en un código genérico multi lenguaje.

Comment: Gracias Javier! Creo que te quedó cortado el código. Pero no tengo c# , uso generador java.  Debe estar x ahi el problema en la iteración, no pude entender el "for" cuando dice: for (i = 0, j = nvert-1; i < nvert; j = i++) no me queda claro como itera i y como itera j . Quizá se pueda resolver con Gx con 2 fors anidados xq no se como escribir esa linea en GX.